# HTML is not recognizing a defined variable in a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I sent a GET request with javascript and parsed the result
    `var result = JSON.parse(response);`
then defined the variable "title"
    `var title = result.title;`
Next I tried to load the variable into a  tag with the id="fishplanet-title"
but HTML gave an error saying "title" wasnt defined.
`document.getElementById("fishplanet-title").innerHTML = title;`
I know the request is going through because I have it logging to console.

Heres the request:
  https://hastebin.com/eloqojimit.js

Heres the response:
https://hastebin.com/vinadafelo.json

Heres the errors:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined
    at user.html:178`

Comment: Please be specific. Post your code: how you make the request, any errors raised or exceptions thrown, and what your "response" actually is. We can't help you if you don't provide enough information.

Comment: Please review [ask], and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46573858/edit) your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`result.title` will not work. The `title` property is within an array so you need to iterate over it to get the `title` value:

```
{
    "appnews": {
        "appid": 380600,
        "newsitems": [
            {
                "gid": "2175660043472720797",
                "title": "QuestionsAnswers",
                "url": "http://store.steampowered.com/news/externalpost/steam_community_announcements/2175660043472720797",
                "is_external_url": true,
                "author": "Olcha",
                "contents": "1.\"What is the garage icon for at the bottom of the Inventory page? Will this be for boat access and when can we expect boats to be launched?\" That’s right - the Garage will soon be the place from where you can access Boats. That’s exactly what we are currently working hard on and we plan to release this feature in the nearest future. Actually, we’ll share a video with you guys next week! Make sure to keep track of our news - it’ll be fun! 2. \"Will we see traditional carp fishing features such a...",
                "feedlabel": "Community Announcements",
                "date": 1506799022,
                "feedname": "steam_community_announcements",
                "feed_type": 1,
                "appid": 380600
            }
        ]
        ,
        "count": 277
    }
}
```

To get to the `title` property, you'll need to do something like this:

`var title = JSON.parse(result).appnews.newsitems[0].title;`

Since newsitems is an array, you will need to do some iterating if that ever returns more than one.